# asp.net webform routing problem with javascript

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, url-routing

I am using asp.net 4 routing and im enjoying it so far. I have one problem only with my javascript files.
I am using a masterpage to add my css and javascript. The css is working fine however the javascript is not.

My links from my masterpage look like this

```
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link href="~/_styles/css/core.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<link href="~/_styles/css/facebox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="~/_styles/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/_styles/js/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="~/_styles/js/facebox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/_styles/js/corejs.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Why does my css load correctly but the js doesnt?

Comment: Can you provide the directory structure as well? Are your js files in the _styles/js folder ?

Comment: Yes I have my my masterpage at the root including my pages. I have then created a folder called _styles which then has folders for css and js

Comment: If I look at the source of the page my links have changed to look like this <link href="../_styles/css/core.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><link href="../_styles/css/facebox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="~/_styles/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/_styles/js/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    
    <script src="~/_styles/js/facebox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/_styles/js/corejs.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: AFAIK `~/_styles` only works for controls with runat=server. try changing the references to simply `/_styles`

Answer (score 3):

This is question is bit old..but i faced same situation using ASP.NET 4.0 routing and referencing different js file or stylesheet when you move from  different directory structure.. what i used to resolve is:

```
<script src='<%=ResolveClientUrl("~/js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js")%>' type="text/javascript"></script>
```

So key was using `ResolveClientUrl`

Hope this helps people in future.

Answer (score 0):

Please check and make sure when you adding the link for your script.You just type the
`<script src="` and Ctrl+Space then choose your file.If you can't find your project path,just try it to get in that path.Sometime,the file will not in that path when you may be copy & paste that file to your project path(not from your VS Project explorer).

Answer (score 0):

you can use simply _styles/js and _styles/css.